# How to change loading data? (From server or cache)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, caching, apollo-client

I'm creating react-native app with login. When user log in I load data with apolo client. Then when user close the app and again open it, it shoud automatically log in and load data from **cache**. But I have no idea how to do it.

Here are my files:

1. Providers.js:

```
export default function Providers() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider forceInset={{top: 'always', bottom: 'always'}}>
      <ApolloProvider client={apoloCLient}>
        <Authprovider>
          <Routes />
        </Authprovider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

2.Authprovider.js:

```
export const MyContext = createContext({});

const AUTH_USER = gql`
  query($name: String!, $key: String!) {
    UserAuth(name: $name, key: $key) {
      AuthStatus
      __typename
    }
  }
`;

export default function AuthProvider({children}) {
  const [callData, {called, loading, data}] = useLazyQuery(AUTH_USER);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  const resetStorage = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user', (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    console.log('cleared');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('1');
    if (data) {
      if (data.UserAuth.AuthStatus === true) {
        setUser(true);
      } else {
        console.log('wrong');
        resetStorage();
        setUser(false);
      }
    }
  }, [data]);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Center>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </Center>
    );
  }

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        data,
        info,
        setInfo,
        LogIn: async (name, passw) => {
          console.log('clicked');
          //Hashing logic
          let HashedName = base64.encode(name);
          let HashedPassw = base64.encode(passw);
          let connect = HashedName + ':' + HashedPassw;

          //getting a key
          let key = base64.encode(connect);
          const info = {name: HashedName, key: key};
          setInfo(info);

          // storing UserInfo, because of authorization
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(info), (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          });

          // calling data
          callData({
            variables: {name: HashedName, key: key},
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
          });
        },
        LogOut: async () => {
          setUser(null);
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user', (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          });
        },
      }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

3.Routes.js:

```
export default function Routes() {
  let {user, setUser, called, data, setInfo} = useContext(MyContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('3');
    //check if the user is logged in or not
    if (!data) {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        .then((userToken) => {
          if (userToken) {
            console.log('userToken ' + userToken);
            setInfo(JSON.parse(userToken));
            setUser(true);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }, []);
  return <>{user ? <AppTabs /> : <AuthTabs />}</>;
}
```

4.AppTabs.js:

```
export default function AppTabs() {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const {info} = useContext(MyContext);
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(GET_USER, {
    variables: info,
  });

  const test = client.readQuery({
    query: GET_USER,
    variables: info,
  });

  //console.log(data);
  console.log(test);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Center>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </Center>
    );
  }

  return (
   .......
  );
}
```

How can I get data in AppTabs from cache, but only if the user is logged in?

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!
Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry I am trying to understand what exactly you are tying to do here that normally you can't do? You query data already if the user logged in via apollo client. Why do you need to get data from the cache? When you query data if it is in the cache, it comes from the cache anyways. Can you help me with understanding the situation better ?

Comment: I thought that, if you close the app you would lose all data. So for faster loading you can get it from cache.

Comment: You need persistent cache, you may want to take a look at this;
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20contents%20of,with%20a%20short%20debounce%20interval).